# Wordpress Custom Post Listings, next/previous, links not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I Know this might be a repost but I have searched the corners of google but to no avail..

Here is my problem:

I am making a movie review site. I have a wordpress custom post( called 'movies') with custom taxonomies (called 'movies-taxonomy')defined. I have two custom templates one to show single movie and other to show list of movies. I am using twenty eleven theme ( I have made a child theme).  The problem is that on movie listings page the next and previous page links are not working. It doesnt even show the next previous links. I have around 24 posts on the blog.

Here is the pastbin url for the Movie Listing template file

http://pastebin.com/EGDA7KKe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`twentyeleven_content_nav()` uses the main query object, $wp_query.

You'll need to use the $wp_query variable, rather than $loop, then wp_reset_query() to restore the original $wp_query.

You also need to define the pagination in your query.

`$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

 $args = array('post_type' => 'movies', 'paged' => $paged );`